# Setter methods can't see child built in parents after_initialize callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

An **Email** has many **Variants** (for ab testing purposes) and always has one set as the **master**

I want to ensure an email always has a master variant built on initialization.

I also want to delegate attr accessors 'subject' and 'body' to the master variant.

I originally tried using

```
delegate :subject, :body, to: :master
```

but rails complained master was nil.

So I tried hand rolling my own subject= setter method and via pry I found that whilst my master is being set in the after_initialize callback, the subsequent call to subject= complains master is nil. I dont understand why.

```
  class Email < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one :master, 
            -> { where is_master: true },
            class_name: 'Tinycourse::Variant',
            dependent: :destroy,
            inverse_of: :email


    def subject=(str)
      master.subject = str # Rails says master is nil here
    end

    #
    # Callbacks
    #-----------------------------------------

    after_initialize :ensure_master
    def ensure_master
      return unless new_record? 
      self.master ||= build_master
    end
  end


Email.new(:subject => 'yah') # undefined method `subject=' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Email.new is initializing the instance, you've got an `after_initialize` so I think this is why it doesn't work.  Does it work if you do `e = Email.new` then `e.subject = 'yah'`?

Comment: Yes it does work if i set after new. However if i place pry in both the after_initialize and the setter method, first pry stops at the after_initialize and then it stops at the setter. So if that's the order, and master is built, why cant the setter see it?

Comment: I don't think it is the order though.  I think it's trying to set it when it initializes, which would be before the master is built.

Answer (score 1):

when your email instance is initialized your `master` is nil, you need to trigger `build_master` before you set anything on it

how about:

```
# app/models/email.rb
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base

  def subject=(str)
    master.subject = str # Rails says master is nil here
  end

  def master
    super || build_master
  end
end
```

Don't know much when and why you need `after_initialize` callback in your project, but if you sure you need this functionality, I would consider to use custom service class to achieve this

```
# app/models/email.rb
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :master, 
          -> { where is_master: true },
          class_name: 'Tinycourse::Variant',
          dependent: :destroy,
          inverse_of: :email

  def subject=(str)
    master.subject = str # this way Rails won't says master is nil here
  end
end

# app/lib/email_builder.rb
class EmailBuilder
  attr_reader :args

  def self.build(args={})
    new(args).build
  end

  def initialize(args)
    @args = args
  end

  def build
    email = Email.new  
    email.build_master
    email.attributes = args
    email
  end   
end

email = EmailBuilder.build subject: 'yah'
email.class # => Email
```

...and another variation of this for persisted record

**Update**

or even better

```
# app/models/email.rb
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :master, 
          -> { where is_master: true },
          class_name: 'Tinycourse::Variant',
          dependent: :destroy,
          inverse_of: :email

end

# app/lib/email_builder.rb
class EmailBuilder
  attr_reader :args, :subject

  def self.build(args={})
    new(args).build
  end

  def initialize(args)
    @subject = args.fetch(:subject)
    @args = args
  end

  def build
    email = Email.new args
    email.build_master
    email.master.subject = subject 
    email
  end   
end

email = EmailBuilder.build subject: 'yah'
email.class # => Email
```

Comment: ...this way  you will extract business logic outside Model, making your model lighter, your tests faster and easier.